# Excel if, then conditions with number values

Tags: excel, formula

I have this excel formula that is a simple concat that rounds the second cell "Q11" to a whole number.

```
 =CONCATENATE(Q12,", ",ROUND(Q11,0))
```

I would like to add a condition to this formula so that if cell Q11 is lower than lets say 5, if it set it to 0.

So if Q12 is 10 and Q11 is 4.09 the formula would produce:

```
 10, 0
```

If Q12 is 10 and Q11 is 5.09 the formula would produce:

```
 10, 5
```

Basically if Q11 is greater than or equal to 5.0, it would show the value.

If Q11 is less than 5, it would show 0.

How do I do this with excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an `If()` formula *inside* the `CONCATENATE` formula:

`=CONCATENATE(Q12,", ",IF(Q11<5,0,ROUND(Q11,0)))`